# Solving Higher Order Partial Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[image]

I can understand until finding the particular solution, I do get substituting $z_{1}$, but according to my solution of first order linear partial differential equation has constants instead of function (I don't know whether it's the right way to solve).

According to the following, the solution contains arbitrary constants

[image]

Help me whether I misunderstood and give hints to solve the problem.

Comment: The integration of a _partial_ derivative yields an integration _function_ . For example, $u_{x}(x,y) = 0 \implies u(x,y) = f(y)$. Note that $f(y)$ can still equal a constant. The second picture means absolutely nothing unless you provide more context. Does $p = z_{x}$, $q = z_{y}$? If so, do you understand why $p-x = q-y = a$, where $a$ is a constant?

Comment: yes,  $p=z_{x}, q = z_{y}$  and isn't $p-x=q-y$ same as $(D-D')*z_{1}=x-y$ ?

Comment: and I don't know why it's equals to constant also I just need some elaboration why I shouldn't solve the 1st one by using 2nd image method in addition even If I use Lagrange's method I getting in the form of $F(c_{1},c_{2})=0 $ (not the answer mentioned in 1st image)