# doubt in solving 1st order linear partial differential equation (lagrange solution)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

$$\partial{z}/\partial{x}-\partial{z}/\partial{y} = x-y $$

so, finding integral curves of
$$dx/1=dy/(-1)=dz/x-y$$
is the above eqaution's solution 
which is
$$x^2-2xy-2z=c_{1}$$$$y^2-2xy-2z=c_{2}$$
therefore $F=(c_{1},c_{2})$

but the given solution is $z=(x-y)^2/4+f(x+y)$

ps: this problem is a sub part of finding higher order partial dif's solution

Comment: link to the original question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2937763/solving-higher-order-partial-differential-equation?noredirect=1#comment6068330_2937763

Comment: It's $\frac 14$ in the book for the answer not $1/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First constant of integration gives
$$dx=-dy \implies x+y=c_1$$
Second constant is given by
$$-dy=\frac {dz}{x-y}$$
$$-\int (x-y)dy=z+c_2$$
Substitute $x=c_1-y$
$$-\int (c_1-2y)dy=z+c_2$$
$$-c_1y+y^2-z=c_2$$
Substitute back $c_1=x+y$
$$xy+z=c_2$$
Therefore
$$z=-xy+f(x+y)$$
You can write $-xy=\frac 14 (-(x+y)^2+(x-y)^2)$
$$\boxed {z(x,y)=\frac 14(x-y)^2+f(x+y)}$$

Comment: $(x+y)^2$ is part of f since it's a function of $x+y$ @jkeasyM

Comment: but this isn't the solution check the image in the link (comment)

Comment: @jkeasyM it's your own mistake the equation in the picture is not the same as what you posted here ...

Comment: isn't same with $z_{1}$ as function

Comment: its a completeley different equation in the picture...@jkeasyM I added some lines see my answer

Comment: The $z_{1}$ equation in the first image

Comment: where $z_{1}=(x-y)^2/4+f(x+y)$

Comment: I added a complete solution for the correct equation in the picture...@jkeasyM

Comment: kindly check the first image solution $(D^2-D'^2)=x-y$

Comment: Both questions are different...what you posted here is a first order equation what you have in the picture is second order  @jkeasyM

Comment: $(D-D^{'})*z_{1}=x-y$ is a linear first order pde with solution $z_{1}=(x-y)^2/4+f(x+y)$

Comment: I see i will add a line to complete my answer and gives the same answzer as your book @jkeasyM

Comment: Does this help you understand the answer of the book @jkeasyM  ????